# Unable to patch array data to prime ng table within a reactive form

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, primeng, formarray

Following JS Mount's tutorial on [how to implement Reactive Form with Prime NG table](https://www.jsmount.com/how-to-implement-reactive-form-with-prime-ng-table/), I created my own. When a static array data provided as below in .ts, all can be properly pre populated.

However, when the data retrieved from API for patching, only the first line was populated and logged an error "ERROR Error: Cannot find form control with name: productId. at FormGroup._throwIfControlMissing...."

I did use "productId" as a parameter for getting the data from API. To my best understanding, it had nothing to do with the from control of the formArray. As provided, the hard coded static data did not contain "productId" either. And all still worked fine.

What on earth dis cause this issue and how should it be resolved? Thanks for any help!

1. .ts

```js
export class EditShippingFeeComponent implements OnInit {
  productId: number;
  shippingFeeForm: FormGroup;
  selectedShippings: any = []; 
  values: any[] = [];

  // values = [
  //   { name: "walk-in", price: "0", days: "0", minValue: "n/a", description: 'Nearby pickup' },
  //   { name: "fastest", price: "7.99", days: "1", minValue: "n/a", description: 'Same day nearby delivery' },
  //   { name: "express", price: "5.99", days: "3", minValue: "n/a", description: 'Regional days shipping' }  
  // ];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private inventoryService: InventoryService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private msgService: MessageService) { 
    this.productId = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getShippingFeeList();
    this.shippingFeeForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      shippingDetails: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    });
    //this.populateData();
  }
getShippingFeeList() {    this.inventoryService.getShippingFeeList(this.productId).subscribe((resp: any[]) => {
      this.values = resp;
      this.populateData();  
    })
  }

get shippingDetails(): FormArray {
    return this.shippingFeeForm.get("shippingDetails") as FormArray;
  }
  
 userDetailsControls(index: number) {
    return this.shippingDetails.controls[index]["controls"];
  }
 
 private addControls() {
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(''),
      price: new FormControl(''),
      days: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }
 
 private populateData() {         
    this.values.forEach((data, index) => {
      this.onAdd();
      this.shippingDetails.controls[index].setValue(data);
    });    
  }
```

2. .html

```html
    <form [formGroup]="shippingFeeForm">
      <div formArrayName="shippingDetails">
        <p-table [value]="shippingDetails.controls" [(selection)]="selectedShippings">
          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 5%"></th>
              <th style="width: 15%">Name</th>
              <th style="width: 40%">Description</th>
              <th style="width: 20%">Fee ($)</th>
              <th style="width: 20%">Days</th>
              <th style="width: 20%">Min Value ($)</th>
            </tr>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-controls let-i="rowIndex">
            <tr [formGroupName]="i">
              <td><p-tableCheckbox [value]="i+1"></p-tableCheckbox></td>
              <td><input type="text" formControlName="name" class="form-control"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" formControlName="description" class="form-control"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" formControlName="price" class="form-control"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" formControlName="days" class="form-control"/></td>
              <td><input type="text" formControlName="minValue" class="form-control"/></td> 
          </ng-template>
        </p-table>
      </div>
    </form>
```

3. what I got:
   [image]
4. I wound expect:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you need replace your this.onAdd() by

```
private populateData() {         
    this.values.forEach((data, index) => {
      //this.onAdd(); //<--replace this line by
      this.shippingDetails.push(this.addControls()) //<--add a new element to the formArray
      this.shippingDetails.controls[index].setValue(data);
    });    
  }
```